# Ninja-stealth upgrading hard drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot

I'm looking to [ninja-stealth upgrade](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/12/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive.html) the laptop in my work computer to an SSD. The current hard drive looks to be a ~250gig spinning rust drive so I bought a similar sized SSD. Unfortunately it seems that the drive I bought is slightly smaller than the current drive.

I proceeded by resizing the partitions on the current drive down. It seems that there are two paritions: the regular C: and a BDEParition which, as I understand it, is used during enterprise deployments of windows. I recreated the partitions on the new drive using fdisk off a linux boot CD and then used dd to copy the partition contents over. The new drive failed to boot at all: just a black screen.

I assume that because the disk geometry is now different that the boot loader, which I believe resides on the BDEPartition, is unable to find windows. I tried booting with a windows disk and running the repair tool but no dice. Any idea how I could get my stealth boot working?

Comment: Evidently, you've chosen a bad-ninja!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you have copied the partitions over, but not the MBR, which is the boot sector.

This is the first 512 bytes of the hard disk (before the partitions begin).  This should copy it over:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1
```

Assuming `sda` is your existing drive and `sdb` is the ssd.